# classification with large number of classes

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Let us say I have a training dataset of 10 million images containing images of 100,000 different people. I want to create an ML model that can identify which person is in a given image.
What would be the best approach considering the huge number of people(classes) ?

Answer (score 6):

One possible approach is to treat this as a verification problem instead of multi-classification. That is, train a binary classifier for each person. You can also consult this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.03832

Answer (score 2):

The number of categories a classifier could classify with good precision/recall is decided by (but not limited to):

how distinct each category is?

how many features you could derive from the content (short text definitely carries much less information here than images) -- since you are using CNN for text, I assume the features would be merely characters or words.

How these features work to differentiate between categories?

how many high-quality labeled examples you have? (We don't have a public labeled large multi-category dataset for short text)

It's hard to just give you a number without knowing the answers to above questions

Answer (score 1):

Try some Boosting algorithms i.e. LightGBM, XGBOOST They are made for such large datasets.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to solve this problem. Convert each image into an embedding vector and then you can use any distance-based measure to classify which image/person is closest. This method was implemented in FaceNet model. Please read about facenet model to know more. This is a face verification problem.